# How to use .NET Core dependency injection to resolve an object which requires an object to it's constructor?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

In my application I have a service which takes some settings in it's constructor

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly Settings _settings

    public Service(Settings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}

public class Settings
{
   // omitted for brevity
}
```

When configuring DI in `Startup.cs` I  add the service:

```
services.AddTransient<Service>();
```

> I don't know configure the DI container to use a `Settings` object. How can I do this?

I have read [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but I can't see how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Injection in .NET works via interfaces. In your case you'll need to create an interface, something like

```
public interface ISettings
{
    // necessary methods
}
```

and make your `Settings` class implement this interface. Then you'll need to change your `Service` class and replace class with an interface:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly ISettings _settings

    public Service(ISettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

and finally register your class `Settings` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddTransient<ISettings, Settings>();
```